# why my must use plugins (mu-plugins) not work at localhost?

Tags: testing, mu-plugins

I have my local WordPress setup I create folder named mu-plugins in wp-content/plugins/mu-plugins and in mu-plugins directory I create one file and write a simple code for test my mu-plugins not work it give no response.

Any One know what shouuld ? (it work fine in live hosting setup)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It does not work because that's not the `mu-plugins` folder.**

The `mu-plugins` folder goes in the `wp-content` folder at `wp-content/mu-plugins`.

Note that `mu-plugins` is not the same as plugin folder, but rather a place that you can put arbitrary PHP files that are all loaded. Files in subfolders are not loaded, and files are not scanned for plugin headers. E.g. if you copy a plugin folder into `wp-content/mu-plugins` it will not run as it's in a sub-folder.

> Any One know what shouuld ? (it work fine in live hosting setup)

Possibly because your host uses a non-standard custom location that serves the same purpose. It's very likely that there is a `wp-content/mu-plugins` folder on your host that contains host specific code, and that host specific code is then implementing a custom folder so that clients can still use `mu-plugins`.

For example, sites hosted on WPVIP Go don't have an `mu-plugins` folder because their Go platform code lives there. Instead customers use `client-mu-plugins` for the same purpose, but that wouldn't work on other hosts. Your host probably does the same.

As a result, when you copy your site to a new host, be that a competing hosting service, or a local hosting environment, it no longer works because it's a non-standard location.

Comment: Thank You So Much Tom for this awesome information not it works fine and I also change the location in live hosting I put mu-plugins at the standard location that is wp-content/mu-plugins